# apt-get update successful, but apt-get upgrade failure to connect

Tags: apt

I keep reading the many similar problems, but the solutions and recommendations are not successful for me.  I thought maybe it was a network problem, but no port is blocked. I finally took of all firewall and still a problem. I have changed sources from US servers, Main Server, and even let Update Manage look for a best server. Still have problem.

Here is what I get:

```
thyme@thyme-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for thyme: 
Ign ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Ign ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Hit ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release   
Hit ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit tp://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit ttp://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
thyme@thyme-Inspiron-1545:~$ 

thyme@thyme-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor apt apt-transport-https apt-utils bind9-host dbus
  dbus-x11 dnsutils firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support
  firefox-locale-en fonts-opensymbol gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gnupg gpgv isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common
  krb5-locales libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libbind9-80
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libdbus-1-3 libdns81 libexif12
  libexpat1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa
  libgssapi-krb5-2 libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
  libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 liblwres80 libnss3 libproxy1
  libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpurple-bin
  libpurple0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-network libqt4-opengl
  libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml
  libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk
  libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer
  librhythmbox-core5 libsmbclient libsnmp-base libsnmp15 libssl1.0.0
  libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtasn1-3 libtiff4 libunity-2d-private0 libwbclient0
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libxatracker1 libxml2 libxslt1.1
  linux-libc-dev multiarch-support openssl python-crypto python-keyring
  python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-software-properties
  python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno qdbus
  rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins
  samba-common samba-common-bin smbclient software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk sudo thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu
  thunderbird-gnome-support transmission-common transmission-gtk tzdata
  ubuntuone-client unity-2d unity-2d-common unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell
  unity-2d-spread uno-libs3 update-manager update-manager-core ure xdiagnose
  xserver-common xserver-xorg-core xul-ext-ubufox
139 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 203 MB/219 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Had to take rest off because hassle to go in and disable links since as new user I am only allowed two links.  Hard to give results with that restriction!

Essentially was continual similar response of:

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/transmission/transmission-common_2.51-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.184 80]
```

Please provide some guidance. I have been using ubuntu since 2007 and never had a problem upgrading or installing new releases.  This has been three days working on this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
It was solved by changing to a server which uses `https` protocol.

Got a hint from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/225683/249188).
*The author provides a list of servers that use `https`*

Note: I had to perform a "search and replace" on my `sources.list` as I could not find `https` mirrors via the GUI.